# Keypress event for jQuery Dropdownchecklist with asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dropdownchecklist

I'm working on adding a keyboard navigation to the multi select drop down which is built by jQuery ui-dropdownchecklist. I was able to capture the keypress by utilising the siblings() method, but having trouble how exactly to bind the click event in there.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ID" Visible="false" selectionChanged="no" runat="server"> 
</asp:ListBox>

function registerDropDownUI() {
    $("select[name$='IDofDropDown']").each(function () {
        $(this).dropdownchecklist({
            firstItemChecksAll: true, emptyText: "Please Select...", minWidth: 270, width: 270, maxDropHeight: 250, icon: {},
            onComplete: function (selector) {
                if (selector.getAttribute("postback") == 'enabled' && selector.getAttribute("selectionChanged") == 'yes') {
                    setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'<%= updParametersPostBack.ClientID %>\',\'\')', 0);
                }
            },
            onItemClick: function (checkbox, selector) {
                selector.setAttribute("SelectionChanged", "yes");
            }
        });
        //this is what I tried to capture the keypress event
        $(this).siblings('span').keyup(function (e) {//Keyup instead of keypress worked!
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $(e.target).click();
             }
        });
    });
}
```

Now, I want to bind the click event inside the keypress method. I am not very familiar with how/what to exactly utilise to make the keypress as click function. Any pointers much appreciate.

Comment: I do not understand the question. I a normal ListBox you can already navigate with the arrows. And the visibility is set to `false` so it does not show up in the html code anyway...

Comment: Right now the dropdown opens with mouse click. I am trying to trigger this with Enter Key(keypress) now

Comment: SOLVED;I had to change the keypress to keyup event. Feels kinda dumb, but learning everyday!